# A function sequence converge to a Fourier series implies point-wise converge?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Assume $f(x)$ is a smooth $2\pi$ periodic function and can be decomposed as 
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{inx}$$
A function sequence $f_m(x)$ satisfies 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}f_m(x)e^{-inx}dx\to a_n,\ m\to\infty,\ \forall n$$
Does this implies $f_m$ converge to $f(x)$, and in what sense?(pointwise, $L_2$?) And what if $f(x)$ belongs to some other function class?

I'm not sure about this, like in a Hilbert space $H$ with orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$, $$\left \langle x_n,e_i \right \rangle \to \left \langle x_0,e_i \right \rangle,\ n\to \infty, \forall i$$ doesn't imply $x_n\to x_0$ (also need $|x_n|$ is bounded, I only know the result but don't know any counterexample). So maybe we can't draw any conclusion from the above?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Thanks, sorry I'm new here...

Comment: I think you need to be very specific about the space that $f$ belongs to. What do you mean my smooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointwise convergence of Fourier coefficients is too weak for such conclusion. Let's take $f\equiv 0$ and $f_m = e^{m(1+ix)}$. Then the convergence of coefficients holds, but $|f_m|\to\infty$ pointwise.

If you also assume that the coefficients are uniformly bounded in $\ell^2$ norm, then weak convergence in $L^2$ holds. That is, $\int f_m g\to \int fg$ for every $g\in L^2$. This still does not imply that $f_m\to f$ in $L^2$, or pointwise.